# MySQL: How can I return the array length of concatenated data stored in a column with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have data stored in a column called **supervisors_id** in a table. The structure of data in this column is like this: **12, 44, 55, 32, 85, 75, 45**. So I want to fetch the total number of ID's in that **supervisors_id** column in a row. My expected result, for instance in the above example should be **7**. How can I do that with a MySQL query ?

Comment: what is the column type of supervisors_id? did you try anything yet to solve this?

Comment: The column type for supervisors_id is text

Answer (score 2):

You can count the commas by comparing the length of the string to the length of the string with commas replaced by the empty string.

Somewhat like:

```
SELECT length(supervisors_id) - length(replace(supervisors_id, ',', '')) + 1
       FROM elbat;
```

If there are also empty strings in the column you might need to add some more logic, that checks for that and returns `0` instead of `1` in that case. For example by using a `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN supervisors_id <> '' THEN
           length(supervisors_id) - length(replace(supervisors_id, ',', '')) + 1
         ELSE
           0
       END
       FROM elbat;
```

But your design is not the best. Instead of a comma delimited list, there should be a linking table.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like magic!! 
Could you just give me a hint of how using it with a linking table would work. I'm just trying to avoid very long rows in a table, but i'm open to new ideas.

Comment: @PhilipOnyango: Welcome! Have a new table, that stores a (as in one) supervisor ID per row and the ID of a row of that other table. I cannot go into more detail as you haven't revealed that much of your schema.

Comment: I already have a parent table for all the supervisors. So in this table called **daily_tasks**, I'm simply concatenating a supervisor's ID whenever a supervisor is assigned a task on that day.

Comment: @PhilipOnyango: Instead of doing that create another table and insert the supervisors ID and the task ID into it.

Comment: I've now fully gotten your point. I think it's a better implementation of my situation. Muchas gracias, I appreciate.